# How to enable multiple click on a button?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<input type="button" id="button" value="8"/>
<script>
button.onclick=function(){

  document.querySelector("#demo").innerText = document.querySelector("#button").value;

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want button to be clicked more than once so i can append button's value and get output something like this `8888` rather than only single digit `8` How is it possible ? Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the line

```
document.querySelector("#demo").innerText = document.querySelector("#button").value
```

To

```
document.querySelector("#demo").innerText += document.querySelector("#button").value
```

This way it appends the value to the paragraph, not set its inner text.

Answer (score 0):

I think with a little more effort, you could have figure this out on your own.  This is not a problem with understanding JS, it is a problem with logic. But here you go...

The problem here is that you are retrieving the previous value of the test box.

```
document.querySelector("#demo").innerText =
```

Is going to set the value of your #demo dive to be what ever comes after equal.

```
document.querySelector("#button").value;
```

Will grab the value of you button which is set to 8. So no matter how many times you run this, it will also set the innerText of #demo to be 8.

All you have to do is grab the current value from #demo before setting its value again.

```
const current = document.querySelector("#demo").innerText;
const next =  current + document.querySelector("#button").value;
document.querySelector("#demo").innerText = next;
```

or

```
document.querySelector("#demo").innerText += document.querySelector("#button").value
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#button").on('click', function(){
                    $("#demo").append($(this).val());
                })
    });//end doc ready
```